# Display SQL XML field data as table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an SQL Table (Table1) with XML field (Field1).

```
<row foo1="foo11" foo2="foo12" foo3="foo13" />
<row foo1="foo21" foo2="foo22" foo3="foo23" />
<row foo1="foo31" foo2="foo32" foo3="foo33" />
```

I need to display data in a table format:

| foo1 | foo2 | foo3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo11 | foo12 | foo13 |
| foo21 | foo22 | foo23 |
| foo31 | foo32 | foo33 |

I tried:

```
 SELECT n.x.value('foo1[1]', 'Varchar(10)') as foo1, 
 n.x.value('foo2[1]', 'Varchar(10)') as foo2, n.x.value('foo3[1]', 
 'Varchar(10)') as foo3
 FROM  Table1
 CROSS APPLY Field1.nodes('/row') n(x)
```

That is not working. I get table that looks like this:

| foo1 | foo2 | foo3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | Null |
| Null | Null | Null |
| Null | Null | Null |

Comment: Well, first your posted code has several syntax errors in it.  We can kinda guess what it _sholud_ be but it would help if you fix what you've posted so we can make sure we're using the same thing you're having an issue with.  Second, "That is not working" is not an error description.  What is the exact error?  Or are the syntax errors what you are having a problem with?

Comment: @lptr. Is there a way to use column order without names. i.e. column1 instead of foo1?